# VirtualBox "Auto resize guest display" greyed out

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos, guest-additions

I have a virtual machine on VirtualBox (version 6.0.6), guest system CentOS 7, host system Windows 10. Extension pack is installed. Graphics controller is VBoxVGA.

I followed [the steps here](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox/CentOSguest) for installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions (no errors displayed) and reboot.

On CentOS:

```
> systemctl -t service | grep vbox
VBoxadd-service.service   loaded active running VBoxadd-service.service
```

(that means guest additions are running). "Auto resize guest display" is still greyed out.

About current kernel:

```
> sudo uname -r
3.10.0-957.12.2.e17.x86_64
```

- [This Q and A](https://superuser.com/questions/721708/virtualbox-suddenly-disabled-auto-resize-guest-display) does not help in my case.
- [This one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430673/auto-resize-guest-display-and-seamless-mode-grayed-out-despite-installing-virtua) does not explain how to get auto-resize working.
- [This is not helpful](https://superuser.com/questions/784811/seamless-mode-and-auto-resize-guest-display-are-grayed-out-disabled-virtualb) as I already installed guest additions.
- [This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452979/resolution-doesnt-change-when-resizing-virtualbox-window) not provide solution.

Note that on the same host, Fedora 30 virtual machine and Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine "auto resize" properly works.

Update: still happens with VirtualBox 6.0.8 (updated Extension Pack and Guest Additions too).

Any hint? What I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue (didn't read all of your references though, short on time) and for me it worked with 3D acceleration enabled and grafics controller `VBoxSVGA`. Noting else changed.

I am on version `6.0.12` on the host and the additions are `6.0.14`.

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to set the display to `VBoxVGA` (VirtualBox 6.1.6 r137129 Qt5.9.5, Guest additions installed, Debian 10)

Comment: ... instead of the suggested `VMSVGA`

Answer (score 0):

Running VirtualBox as a superuser (or Administrator in Windows) resulted with ungrayed “Auto resize guest display” button, thus solving the issue for me.